# Can we use multi xaml layout on a window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, stretch

I think that we can use multi layout on a windows with XAML.
So I try to create a window like this:
I want to create an ListView in left and it can be resized. The Grid and Textbox at the left side will be fit to the right grid.
I have tried to use other layouts, StackPanel, DockPanel.
How can I create a resizable grid

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToolBar Name="toolBar" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Name="btnLoad" Width="Auto" Height="25" ToolTip= Click="btnLoad_Click" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Resources/reload.png" Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                <TextBlock>Load/Reload</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="btnSave" Width="Auto" Height="25"  Click="btnSave_Click">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="Resources/save.png" Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                <TextBlock>Save</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>
    <ComboBox Name="cbTypeOfShop" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5 5 5 5"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black" ShowsPreview="true" Width="5"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <DataGrid Name="dtgListItem" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            </DataGrid>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="100" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="1231231231 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222221231231231231231123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123123" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="3" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Name="abc">abc</TextBlock>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

[image: I need that the datagrid at left will be resize and fit on grid cell when I use the gridsplitter.]

But when I resize the left side.

[image: But when I resize the left side.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**try this**

```
    <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Left side</TextBlock>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontSize="55" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">Right side</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

As you can see, I've simply created a Grid with two equally wide columns, with a 5 pixel column in the middle.

[image]

Comment: Your code work well, but I need my datagrid be resize when I use gridsplitter. Please see the image of my windows what I updated.

Comment: @ONLAEG you must have need to check 'GridSplitter'

Comment: @ONLAEG You must have change #ColumnDefinition

Comment: It right. I changed the `GridSplitter` from `VerticalAlignment=Stretch` to `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch`. It works. But I do not understand why. Could you explain for me?

Comment: @ONLAEG  The HorizontalAlignment enumeration has the four properties Left, Center, Right and Stretch. The Left, Center and Right properties sets a child element to left, center and right of the parent element. The Stretch property stretches a child element to fill the parent element's allocated layout space.

Comment: In your code, Width of Grid's column 1 is 5, and Width of gridsplitter is 5 too. `VerticalAlignment=Stretch` has not effect, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182013/discussion-between-sanjay-ranavaya-and-onlaeg).